# KMM - How to set iOS deployment target?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to initialize a KMM project. On the initialization page it asks for `minSdk` version for Android but not for iOS.

The only way I could find was to traverse the files and manually change iOS deployment target in all of them. I even opened the project in XCode and changed the deployment target in XCode but it did not affect anything either.

Is there any proper workaround or official solution to change iOS deployment target?

Answer (score 1):

No need to manually change XCode project files, you should:

0. Open iOS project in XCode
1. Select project file
2. Go to `Build Settings`
3. Search for `ios deployment`
4. Change iOS deployment target
5. Commit changes they will be in `iosApp/iosApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`  if you are using standard KMM template

[image]